# Cloud Functions: dns.resolveTxt() returns ESERVFAIL

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm running into an issue when calling dns.resolveTxt() from Node's DNS module in a Cloud Function (tried on both Node6 and Node8)

I am using an account with billing enabled (Firebase on Blaze plan), and dns.lookup() calls are working as expected, so I don't think that it's related to calls to external domains being blocked.

Example code:

```
var dns = require('dns');

dns.resolveTxt('google.com', function (err, addresses) {
  console.log(addresses, err);
});
```

Returns proper results when run locally:

```
[ [ 'docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e' ],
  [ 'facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95' ],
  [ 'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all' ] ] null
```

When executed in a Cloud Function, thew following error is returned:

```
{ Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL google.com
  at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:213:19)
  errno: 'ESERVFAIL',
  code: 'ESERVFAIL',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'google.com'
}
```

Comment: Are you able to fetch other record types such as A or NS? You might need to first fetch the default resolver for the domain and then query that resolver directly.

Comment: Some other resolver are working but not all. I also tried instancing a resolver and using it for the various queries with same results. What I tested:

Working: resolve4(), resolveNs()

Not working: resolve(), resolveMx(), resolveTxt(), resolveAny()

All fail with error similar to the one in the main description, ESERVFAIL.

Comment: I mean use the DNS server for the domain name as indicated by the NS record. I did not mean use a different function call. In Python your would use this type of code: `default = dns.resolver.get_default_resolver()` `nameserver = default.nameservers[0]`

Comment: Once you know the  "authoritative" name server for the domain, query it for TXT records.

Comment: Thanks John, that worked! :-)

Comment: Can you post your final source code as an answer? This will others understand how to use DNS queries in Node.js